# Update same tables from from select value from same table mysql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to update a table column which same column from same table select.
Here is the code (updated)

```
     public function UpdateStockIn($id, $subUnitValue) {
    $query = "UPDATE BRAND_LIST SET CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE = (SELECT CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE FROM BRAND_LIST WHERE ID = ?) + '.$subUnitValue.' WHERE ID = ? ";
    $success = 0;
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $id);

        $stmt->execute();
        $success = 1;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return $success;
}
```

it Show error like this
      You can't specify target table 'BRAND_LIST' for update in FROM clause

Comment: why $subUnitValue in your query??

Comment: Your query makes no sense, because the subquery is not correlated.  Please tell us, in clear English, what you are trying to do here.

Comment: i want plus $subUnitValue  with selected value

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Mysql does not support this type of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query

```
$query = "UPDATE BRAND_LIST SET CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE = CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE + ".$subUnitValue."  WHERE ID = ?";
```

Comment: fine but still sql error , like this 'QLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'BRAND_LIST' for update in FROM clause'

Comment: Check now and remove $stmt->bindParam(2, $id); line

Answer (score 3):

**Try run these 2 sqls, The first one will store a value into mysql local variable then use into 2nd sql.**

```
 SELECT @old_subUnitValue := GROUP_CONCAT(table1.CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE) FROM BRAND_LIST AS table1 WHERE table1.ID=2;

 UPDATE BRAND_LIST AS table2 SET table2.CURRENT_STOCK_BOTTLE =  @old_subUnitValue + '.$subUnitValue.' WHERE table2.ID=2;
```